# How to Check if Jacobian is Correct

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, numerical-integration

I am happily integrating a simple ODE with scipy.odeint. This is my integration fuction:

```
def f(self, x, t_0):
    h = x[0:3]
    f = x[3:6]

    der = []

    der.append((self.q_0 - f[0] * self.u[0] * self.k[0] * numpy.sign(h[0] - h[1]) * numpy.sqrt(abs(h[0] - h[1]))) / self.A[0])
    der.append((f[0] * self.u[0] * self.k[0] * numpy.sign(h[0] - h[1]) * numpy.sqrt(abs(h[0] - h[1])) -
                f[1] * self.u[1] * self.k[1] * numpy.sign(h[1]) * numpy.sqrt(abs(h[1]))) / self.A[1])
    der.append((f[1] * self.u[1] * self.k[1] * numpy.sign(h[1] - h[2]) * numpy.sqrt(abs(h[1] - h[2])) -
                f[2] * self.u[2] * self.k[2] * numpy.sign(h[2]) * numpy.sqrt(abs(h[2]))) / self.A[2])
    der.append(0)
    der.append(0)
    der.append(0)

    return numpy.array(der)
```

Everything works fine if I call scipy.integrate.odeint except I decided to provide the Jacobian so I can do the integration faster. This is the Jacobian which I figured out by hand:

```
def F(self, x, t_0):
    h = x[0:3]
    f = x[3:6]

    u = self.u
    k = self.k
    A = self.A

    result = numpy.zeros((6, 6))

    sqrt_diff_h0_h1 = numpy.sign(h[0] - h[1]) * numpy.sqrt(abs(h[0] - h[1]))
    sqrt_diff_h1_h2 = numpy.sign(h[1] - h[2]) * numpy.sqrt(abs(h[1] - h[2]))
    sqrt_diff_h1 = numpy.sign(h[1]) * numpy.sqrt(abs(h[1]))
    sqrt_diff_h2 = numpy.sign(h[2]) * numpy.sqrt(abs(h[2]))

    result[0][0] = -(u[0] * f[0] * k[0]) / (2 * A[0] * sqrt_diff_h0_h1)
    result[0][1] = (u[0] * f[0] * k[0]) / (2 * A[0] * sqrt_diff_h0_h1)
    result[0][3] = -(u[0] * k[0] * sqrt_diff_h0_h1) / A[0]
    result[1][0] = (u[0] * f[0] * k[0]) / (2 * A[1] * sqrt_diff_h0_h1)
    result[1][1] = -((u[0] * f[0] * k[0] * A[1]) / (2 * sqrt_diff_h0_h1)) - \
                   ((u[1] * f[1] * k[1] * A[1]) / (2 * sqrt_diff_h1))
    result[1][3] = (u[0] * k[0] * sqrt_diff_h0_h1) / A[1]
    result[1][4] = -(u[1] * k[1] * sqrt_diff_h1) / A[1]
    result[2][1] = (u[1] * f[1] * k[1]) / (2 * A[2] * sqrt_diff_h1_h2)
    result[2][2] = -((u[1] * f[1] * k[1] * A[2]) / (2 * sqrt_diff_h1_h2)) - \
                   ((u[2] * f[2] * k[2] * A[2]) / (2 * sqrt_diff_h2))
    result[2][4] = (u[1] * k[1] * sqrt_diff_h1_h2) / A[2]
    result[2][5] = -(u[2] * k[2] * sqrt_diff_h2) / A[2]

    return result
```

If I supply F to scipy.odeint.integrate, it actually takes more time. This, of course, doesn't mean much but I am wondering how to determine if the Jacobian is correct? I need it for other purposes of linearization.

Comment: To me, _the_ defining feature of the entire domain of computer science is the use of the word "simple" to describe things that aren't.

Comment: [Scipy provides a function `check_grad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.check_grad.html) which I think might give you just what you need.